# Use ttf font in NextJS application correctly

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, fonts

I am using my local fonts in my `NextJS` application and via my `globals.css` and it works fine by like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "PrometoRegular";
  src: local("PrometoRegular");
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Prometo-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
h1 {
  font-family: "PrometoRegular";
  color: black;
}
```

But when I want to do this in a component:
`import PrometoRegular from '../../../assets/fonts/Prometo-Regular.ttf';`

It returns me `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file`

How can I configure my `next.config.js` file so it will work?

Comment: why would you need to import the font file into a component, what's your use case? If you have set the font-face in `global.css` you should be able to use it as a style.

Comment: Because I am using this: https://react-pdf.org/fonts

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://react-pdf.org/fonts#register), it mentioned that

> **source**
> Specifies the source of the font. This can either be ***a valid URL***, or ***an absolute path*** if you're using react-pdf on Node.

You can put it at your public directory and put it as a url.